# Javascript setInterval not being cleared

Tags: javascript

For some reason, the timer is not being cleared from the code below:

```
var countdown = function() {
    if (!interval || !countdownOngoing) {
        countdownOngoing = true;
        interval = setInterval(countdownFunction, 1000);
    }
};

function countdownFunction() {
    if(seconds == 0) {
        if (minutes == 0) {
            countdownOngoing = false;
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        } else {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 60;
        }
    }

    seconds--;
}
```

The setInterval is still working after the clearInterval. What am I missing?

Comment: Where is `interval` defined?

Comment: @Phil It looks like interval is a global variable bound to window

Comment: put `var interval;` outside the function

Comment: Print the values of minutes and seconds to the console, looks like the clearInterval is never called

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9asDB/.  I'm not sure what's different in my jsfiddle vs. your real code.  You don't show all the variables being declared as globals (which is a safer way to code if you need globals), but I'm not sure that's actually the issue.

Comment: It now appears obvious that there is something else wrong in your code  outside of what you have put in your question and we cannot help you solve your issue without further disclosure and you have not answered any questions about such additional disclosure.  As such, I guess this question should be closed.  If you want to get an answer here on StackOverflow, you should not post a question and then disappear.  You main window of opportunity to get an answer is the first 20-30 minutes so you MUST be available to clarify things.  If not, you will miss most people who could help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it looks something like what I wrote below, it's probably your minute + seconds logic.

```
var interval = null,
countDownGoing = false;

function countdown() {
    if(!interval || !countDownGoing) {
         interval = setInterval(countdownFunction, 1 * 1000);   
        countDownGoing = true;
    }
}

countdown()

setTimeout(function() {
    countDownGoing = false;
}, 5 * 1000);


function countdownFunction() {
    if(!countDownGoing) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        alert(countDownGoing);
    }
}
```